# React npm run build homepage doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm fairly new in using React, and I want to deploy the app I've made to web hosting. I've specified the homepage in the package.json and yet in the terminal it says the project is hosted at root. How can I solve this? [image]

Comment: it is saying correct, you have to upload the files in the dist folder to your domain's directory.

Comment: so is it fine as long as I specified the homepage, and then zip the build folder so I can upload it straight away?

Comment: yes, the root specified is the root of the domain. if you want to host the app on a sub folder it will say `/subfolder/`.